# Oracle Date Time function issue

Tags: oracle, datetime

When I execute following query it returns correct:

```
 select to_date('24-OCT-19' || ' ' || '0900' ,'dd-Mon-rr hh24mi')   from dual;
```

Result >> 24/10/2019 9:00:00 AM

But when I use into clause and store the result in some variable it only shows date (time is truncated):

```
select to_date('24-OCT-19' || ' ' || '0900' ,'dd-Mon-rr hh24mi') into Res from dual;
```

Result : Res = 24-OCT-19

Comment: Your query works as expected. That's just a display issue.

Comment: depends on how you defined the variable `Res`. Moreover if you qualify with a colon (`select to_date('24-OCT-19' || ' ' || '0900' ,'dd-Mon-rr hh24mi') into :Res from dual;`), then it also gives the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behaviour.

You need to ser `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter to desired format. (At session or database level)

To see current value of aforementioned parameter in your session, you can use `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` view.

To set it at session level, you can use following command in your session:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

SELECT YOUR_DATE FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

also, while displaying the date you can set it in to_char function if it is not allowed to set it at session level.

```
Select to_char(your_date, 'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS') from your_table;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
declare 
v_res timestamp;
Begin 
   select to_date('24-OCT-19' || ' ' || '0900' ,'dd-Mon-rr hh24mi', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American' ) into v_res
   from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(v_res);
end;
```